# RealTime XY Plot X-Axis update

Tags: android, androidplot

I'm using the Realtime Orientation Sensor Plot demo from the AndroidPlot library. How can I make the Domain x-axis values update when the graph scrolls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scroll and zoom example in the Androidplot DemoApp does this - [here's a link to the source](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/d90fc9fe7705a3f82fe44406cd28a34d9169e056/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/TouchZoomExampleActivity.java?at=master).  In particular take a look at [Line #153](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/d90fc9fe7705a3f82fe44406cd28a34d9169e056/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/TouchZoomExampleActivity.java?at=master#cl-153); that's where the where scrolling is handled.

Comment: Is it possible to get this sample code for Realtime Orientation Sensor Plot anywhere? It's no longer available on the website. I need realtime dynamic plotting for my app. I tried to look it up, but they are also gone from BitBucket...
@Anthony, maybe you could help me with that too?

Comment: It's all still available in the same place as always on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot) and is also available on [Github](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot).  Also [here's a direct link](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/d90fc9fe7705a3f82fe44406cd28a34d9169e056/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/OrientationSensorExampleActivity.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) to the realtime sensor demo source.